# How to use hp.x in Quantum ESPRESSO to calculate Hubbard parameter

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, model-hamiltonians, dft-u, hubbard-model

I want to work with GGA +U on Quantum espresso to calculate the electronic properties of Ni Co co-doped ZnO system, but I can't figure out how to use the hp.x program for my system to calculate the Hubbard parametre for each element

is there someone who can give me an example of an input and output file  of hp.x program to better understand how I work with it.

my input files for `SCF`:

```
&CONTROL
    calculation='scf'
    verbosity='high'
    outdir  ='./outdir0'
    prefix  = 'zno'
/
&SYSTEM

    celldm(1)                 =  21.40319287
    celldm(3)                 =  0.42031128
    degauss                   =  1.00000e-02
    ecutrho                   =  2.25000e+02
    ecutwfc                   =  2.50000e+01
    ibrav                     = 4
    lda_plus_u                = .TRUE.
    nat                       = 64
    nspin                     = 2
    ntyp                      = 4
    occupations               = "smearing"
    smearing                  = "gaussian"
    starting_magnetization(1) =  0.00000e+00
    starting_magnetization(2) =  0.00000e+00
    starting_magnetization(3) =  1.00000e+00
    starting_magnetization(4) =  1.00000e+00
/

&ELECTRONS
    conv_thr         =  1.00000e-06
    electron_maxstep = 1000
    mixing_beta      =  7.00000e-01
    startingpot      = "atomic"
    startingwfc      = "atomic+random"
/

K_POINTS {automatic}
 1  1  2  0 0 0

ATOMIC_SPECIES
Zn     65.39000  Zn.pbe-dnl-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
O      15.99940  O.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
Co     58.93320  Co.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.0.3.1.UPF
Ni     58.69340  Ni.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF

ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
Zn       1.410161044   0.825995833   2.380992801
Zn      -0.005429322   1.643266003   0.000756804
O        1.411103994   0.826287146   4.186635975
O       -0.004748346   1.642515898   1.806356445
Zn      -0.005516345   3.278786045   2.381245055
Zn      -1.419971282   4.097701065   0.001850277
O       -0.002798492   3.277411927   4.186681410
O       -1.420408761   4.092914533   1.803518434
Co      -1.418796177   5.737987580   2.384585461
Zn      -2.834720550   6.547227769   0.000881320
O       -1.422621217   5.728278992   4.185274022
O       -2.839808876   6.544154464   1.803705508
Zn      -2.837557287   8.183674136   2.381283724
Zn      -4.252922611   8.999365922   0.000439200
O       -2.837160076   8.183295309   4.186352705
O       -4.252778394   8.999185384   1.806247618
Zn       4.241315211   0.825532190   2.381126062
Zn       2.826326309   1.643228258   0.000953899
O        4.242086608   0.827637833   4.187714131
O        2.826296455   1.642373986   1.806396627
Zn       2.824771427   3.281480594   2.381223601
Zn       1.410630100   4.096454188   0.000348962
O        2.829294361   3.277876925   4.186011005
O        1.408295070   4.091216703   1.805811442
Zn       1.414986914   5.731953488   2.381740527
Zn      -0.003889577   6.546816914   0.001471199
O        1.407469304   5.728334147   4.188751652
O       -0.007390107   6.544762033   1.803264178
Zn      -0.003327618   8.182005863   2.381621288
Zn      -1.420174649   8.999121824   0.000605799
O       -0.005038456   8.183109394   4.186299484
O       -1.422019740   8.999623285   1.805713335
Zn       7.074368960   0.824266725   2.381038272
Zn       5.658165161   1.641466511   0.001428145
O        7.072366692   0.826925817   4.185876987
O        5.657781142   1.643195079   1.806011335
Zn       5.660936107   3.273250277   2.380793392
Zn       4.239021566   4.101799131   0.000974597
O        5.656833118   3.276218912   4.184993975
O        4.230283881   3.987942736   1.752313988
Ni       4.556125575   5.359987165   2.507242555
Zn       2.822577415   6.549618757  -0.002501852
O        4.241256251   5.729384302   4.181685069
O        2.889746313   6.512400957   1.840699848
Zn       2.831814541   8.170887246   2.382231895
Zn       1.411768031   8.997746180   0.000157807
O        2.830565389   8.180204499   4.188372520
O        1.410158759   9.000713184   1.805698039
Zn       9.904721317   0.824048816   2.380672192
Zn       8.489987876   1.641958804   0.000861323
O        9.905515013   0.828559672   4.186395649
O        8.489434493   1.643995005   1.805707065
Zn       8.491348975   3.277332149   2.381672239
Zn       7.075554658   4.094592895  -0.001192399
O        8.487517217   3.277350003   4.187187336
O        7.079637920   4.091302394   1.804853403
Zn       7.070336637   5.730421815   2.381711957
Zn       5.657529623   6.551672595   0.003357063
O        7.061570500   5.730823283   4.183934701
O        5.626730523   6.537239405   1.818160581
Zn       5.654350538   8.182766059   2.381132006
Zn       4.240971534   8.998159127   0.002754675
O        5.659147597   8.182586948   4.186976982
O        4.243691097   8.999467758   1.805287550
```

and `NSCF`:

```
&CONTROL
        calculation='nscf'
        verbosity='high'
        outdir  ='./outdir0'
        prefix  = 'zno'
    /
    &SYSTEM
        celldm(1)                 =  21.40319287
        celldm(3)                 =  0.42031128
        degauss                   =  1.00000e-02
        ecutrho                   =  2.25000e+02
        ecutwfc                   =  2.50000e+01
        ibrav                     = 4
        lda_plus_u                = .TRUE.
        nat                       = 64
        nbnd                      = 416
        nspin                     = 2
        ntyp                      = 4
        occupations               = "smearing"
        smearing                  = "gaussian"
        starting_magnetization(1) =  0.00000e+00
        starting_magnetization(2) =  0.00000e+00
        starting_magnetization(3) =  1.00000e+00
        starting_magnetization(4) =  1.00000e+00
    /
    
    &ELECTRONS
        conv_thr         =  1.00000e-06
        electron_maxstep = 1000
        mixing_beta      =  7.00000e-01
        startingpot      = "atomic"
        startingwfc      = "atomic+random"
    /
    K_POINTS {automatic}
     2  2  5  0 0 0
    
    ATOMIC_SPECIES
    Zn     65.39000  Zn.pbe-dnl-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
    O      15.99940  O.pbe-n-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
    Co     58.93320  Co.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.0.3.1.UPF
    Ni     58.69340  Ni.pbe-spn-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
    
    ATOMIC_POSITIONS {angstrom}
    Zn       1.410161044   0.825995833   2.380992801
    Zn      -0.005429322   1.643266003   0.000756804
    O        1.411103994   0.826287146   4.186635975
    O       -0.004748346   1.642515898   1.806356445
    Zn      -0.005516345   3.278786045   2.381245055
    Zn      -1.419971282   4.097701065   0.001850277
    O       -0.002798492   3.277411927   4.186681410
    O       -1.420408761   4.092914533   1.803518434
    Co      -1.418796177   5.737987580   2.384585461
    Zn      -2.834720550   6.547227769   0.000881320
    O       -1.422621217   5.728278992   4.185274022
    O       -2.839808876   6.544154464   1.803705508
    Zn      -2.837557287   8.183674136   2.381283724
    Zn      -4.252922611   8.999365922   0.000439200
    O       -2.837160076   8.183295309   4.186352705
    O       -4.252778394   8.999185384   1.806247618
    Zn       4.241315211   0.825532190   2.381126062
    Zn       2.826326309   1.643228258   0.000953899
    O        4.242086608   0.827637833   4.187714131
    O        2.826296455   1.642373986   1.806396627
    Zn       2.824771427   3.281480594   2.381223601
    Zn       1.410630100   4.096454188   0.000348962
    O        2.829294361   3.277876925   4.186011005
    O        1.408295070   4.091216703   1.805811442
    Zn       1.414986914   5.731953488   2.381740527
    Zn      -0.003889577   6.546816914   0.001471199
    O        1.407469304   5.728334147   4.188751652
    O       -0.007390107   6.544762033   1.803264178
    Zn      -0.003327618   8.182005863   2.381621288
    Zn      -1.420174649   8.999121824   0.000605799
    O       -0.005038456   8.183109394   4.186299484
    O       -1.422019740   8.999623285   1.805713335
    Zn       7.074368960   0.824266725   2.381038272
    Zn       5.658165161   1.641466511   0.001428145
    O        7.072366692   0.826925817   4.185876987
    O        5.657781142   1.643195079   1.806011335
    Zn       5.660936107   3.273250277   2.380793392
    Zn       4.239021566   4.101799131   0.000974597
    O        5.656833118   3.276218912   4.184993975
    O        4.230283881   3.987942736   1.752313988
    Ni       4.556125575   5.359987165   2.507242555
    Zn       2.822577415   6.549618757  -0.002501852
    O        4.241256251   5.729384302   4.181685069
    O        2.889746313   6.512400957   1.840699848
    Zn       2.831814541   8.170887246   2.382231895
    Zn       1.411768031   8.997746180   0.000157807
    O        2.830565389   8.180204499   4.188372520
    O        1.410158759   9.000713184   1.805698039
    Zn       9.904721317   0.824048816   2.380672192
    Zn       8.489987876   1.641958804   0.000861323
    O        9.905515013   0.828559672   4.186395649
    O        8.489434493   1.643995005   1.805707065
    Zn       8.491348975   3.277332149   2.381672239
    Zn       7.075554658   4.094592895  -0.001192399
    O        8.487517217   3.277350003   4.187187336
    O        7.079637920   4.091302394   1.804853403
    Zn       7.070336637   5.730421815   2.381711957
    Zn       5.657529623   6.551672595   0.003357063
    O        7.061570500   5.730823283   4.183934701
    O        5.626730523   6.537239405   1.818160581
    Zn       5.654350538   8.182766059   2.381132006
    Zn       4.240971534   8.998159127   0.002754675
    O        5.659147597   8.182586948   4.186976982
    O        4.243691097   8.999467758   1.805287550
```

Comment: +1 but you only get a maximum of 5 tags so why waste two of them on VASP and Wien2K for a QE question? I've added the DFT+U and Hubbard tags, you can replace them as you see fit.

Comment: Have you checked out the HP folder in your QE folder? It has ~ 10 examples with detailed documentation. IMO it is the best starting point.

Comment: This question will be closed temporarily as an "abandoned question" until the question by Xivi76 gets answered. When you come back, just answer Xivi76's question in a comment, and we'll re-open it if you ping a moderator [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110431/ask-a-moderator)!